# Need Assistance with Security assessment on Flutter compiled binaries

Tags: android, flutter, security

I'm developing an android app using flutter but during vulnerability assessment client have raised security concerns on flutter compiled arm-based binaries.

1. NX - The shared object does not have an NX bit set. NX bit offers protection against
   exploitation of memory-corruption vulnerabilities by marking the memory page as non-
   executable. Use option --noexecstack or -z noexecstack to mark the stack as non-
   executable.
2. STACK CANARY - This shared object does not have a stack canary value added to
   the stack. Stack canaries are used to detect and prevent exploits from overwriting
   return address. Use the option - fstack- protector- all to enable stack canaries.
3. No RELRO - This shared object does not have RELRO enabled. The entire GOT (.got and .got.plt both) are writable. Without this compiler flag, buffer overflows on a global
   variable can overwrite GOT entries. Use the option -z,relro,- z,now to enable full
   RELRO and only -z,relro to enable partial RELRO.

Files: lib/armeabi-v7a/libapp.so (1,2,3), lib/mips/libmodpdfium.so (3), lib/armeabi-v7a/libtool-checker.so (2)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does your app also includes libraries for armv8a (that architecture was not mentioned in your question)? Because this architecture is the most relevant one. MIPS architecture is dead and totally irrelevant for Android phones (you can disable that architecture). arm-v7a is legacy, used by older devices (>4 years). So if you want you could disable that architecture, too.

Comment: Yes, My app includes both armv8 & arm-v7, I'm generating a fat apk because the client is using older devices which include Marshmallow, and Lollipop.

Comment: LOL, and then they complain about not using certain security features on assembler level in the libraries?

Comment: Is there anything I can do now?

Comment: Hello @VisheshPandey did you have any resolution to this problem?

Comment: @KeithOYS Not yet.